# Find a certain tag in HTML with web scraping

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm doing web scraping on different html pages with a for loop, and I need to find for every page a certain tag (I'm using BeautifulSoup and find_all method). But not in all the pages that tag exist. So I need to find a simple way to check if that tag exist. I've tried to write this code in order to check if the tag does not exist, but it does not work.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [92], in <cell line: 5>()
     36 sal_play = salary.find_all('tr')[1:]
     37 print(sal_play)
---> 38 if sal_play.find_all('tr', class_='thead') is None :
     39     print('1')
     40 else:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: `goal = soup.select("tr.thead"); if goal: print(goal)`

Comment: first `find_all` gives you list and you have to use `for`-loop to run second `find_all` on every element separatelly.

Comment: thanks @furas, finally understood the problem! I was calling the find_all on the wrong element as you said. Anyway I've used the select method in my code since it was better readable (I'm doing a sort of thesis about web scraping). You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is saying, you can't run `find` on a list directly - you have to run it on each item

If you want to print '1' only if *none of them* have heading row use:

```py
if not [s for s in sal_play if s.find('tr', class_='thead')]: 
    print('1')
```

or if you want to print '1' as long *some* of them *don't* have a heading row use:

```py
if [s for s in sal_play if s.find('tr', class_='thead') is None]: 
    print('1')
```

By the way, if a tag does not exist, `find_all` will return an empty list (`[]`) and  `find` will return `None`, so `if ...find_all(....) is None: do x` will pretty much make sure x never happens....